# Div with display: flex by default still taking up space after style is changed to display: none as well as all children of that div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been making a menu page for a tiny game, and when the user clicks on the start button, the container containing the title of the game and start button is set to change it's display to "display: none;"

```js
let container = document.getElementById("container")
let title = document.getElementById("title")
let startButton = document.getElementById("startBtn")

function init(){


startButton.style.display = "none"
container.style.diplay = "none"
title.style.display = "none"



}

startButton.onclick = init
```

```css
#container {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

#title {
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  font-size: 3em;
     
}

#startBtn {
  width: 15%;
  height: 7%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color:#b8b6b0;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id = "container">
            <div id = "title"><span id = "untitled">Untitled</span> Pew Pew Game</div>
            <button type = "button" id = "startBtn">Start</button>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The result is expected, as the div disappears. However, in the console, it appears that the container div is still taking up space.

[Elements Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngkHc.png)

When checking the display style of the container div in console, and empty string is returned.

> ```
> > container.style.display
> <-""
> ```

I've also double checked the names and id's of the divs, and they match up as well.

What else could be causing this space?

Comment: Currently there is a typo in the line setting the container to display as none. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo, thank you so much

Comment: Try to use: `container.style.display = "none!important";` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is fine.  The height of the container (after you press start) is 0.  To see that in dev tools  (chrome) click on the container and then look where it says styles computed event listeners and click on computed.  scroll down to height and you'll see it's 0px